# Show that there exists two closed sets $A, B$ such that $m(A)=m(B)=0$ but $m(A+B)>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I think this is a partial solution to this problem in Stein and Sharkarchi's Real Analysis.

Since the most obvious choice for a closed set with measure 0 is the Cantor set, $\mathcal{C}$, we should set $A=B=\mathcal{C}$. I also know that $$\mathcal{C} = \big\{\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k3^{-k}: a_k\in\{0,2\},\, \forall k\big\} $$

So $$\mathcal{C}+\mathcal{C} = \big\{\sum_{k=1}^\infty (a_k+b_k)3^{-k}: a_k,b_k\in\{0,2\}, \, \forall k\big\}$$

I think that $[0,1]\subset\mathcal{C}+\mathcal{C}$ but I can find any concrete way of showing this. I know that I can find an $x,y\in\mathcal C$ such that $x+y = 3^{-k}$ for each $k$, but I can't see how to get an infinite number of the numbers in the ternary expansion to be 1.

Comment: You could make life easier on yourself by only allowing ones and zeros in $C$.

Comment: $C$ is a good choice, because $C+C=[0,2]$. You can show this by showing that $C_n+C_n=[0,2]$ where $C_n$ is what's left after removing middle thirds $n$ times. You can see this visually by drawing $C_n\times C_n$ in the plane and seeing how the image of $C_n\times C_n$ under the projection map $(x,y)\to x+y$ is the whole interval $[0,2]$.

Comment: I suppose if you have zeros, twos and fours in a sum, that's the same as having double a number with zeros, ones and twos. So bof is correct. What I just said is a simpler proof for me to understand, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One easy way of showing that $C+C=[0,2]$ is to note that any number $t$ in $[0,1]$ can be written as $x+y$ where the base $3$ expansions of both $x$ and $y$ only have $0$s and $1$s. For instance, if the base three expansion of $t$ is $0.1221012\dots$, take $x=0.1111011\dots$ and $y=0.0110001\dots$ That means that $2t$ is the sum of two numbers in $[0,1]$ whose base $3$ expansions only have $0$s and $2$s, that is, $2t$ is the sum of two numbers in $C$. But any number in $[0,2]$ is $2t$ for some $t\in[0,1]$. This shows that $[0,2]\subseteq C+C$, and the other containment is obvious.