# Show that $f: C_{n} \times C_{n}/2 \to [0,1]$ given by $f(x,y) = x+y$ is surjective. ($C_{n}$ is the $n$-step of construction of the Cantor Set)

Tags: measure-theory, cantor-set

> [Show that there exists two closed sets $A, B$ such that $m(A)=m(B)=0$ but $m(A+B)>0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1019607/444015)

My question is very similar to this. The difference is that I am required to use $A = \mathcal{C}$ and $\displaystyle B = \frac{\mathcal{C}}{2}$. I'm trying to use the bof's ideia, that is:

Consider the projection

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{C}_{n} \times \frac{\mathcal{C}_{n}}{2} & \longrightarrow & [0,1]\\
(x,y) & \mapsto x + y
\end{eqnarray*}$$
and to show that is surjective in each $n$, where $n$ is the $n$-th step of construction of the Cantor Set. The problem is, I can see and show that this is true for $n = 1, 2,\dots$; but I'm not able to correctly show that it's worth for all $n$. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1:** $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{C}_n$  so if the same map restricted to $\mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C}/2$ is surjective, then so is the original map.

**Hint 2:** The Cantor set $\mathcal{C}$ is the set of all real numbers in $[0,1]$ that can be expressed using $0$ and $2$ in base $3$. Similarly, $\mathcal{C}/2$ is the set of all real numbers in $[0,1]$ that can be expressed using $0$ and $1$ in base $3$.

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to use restrictions, then use the following

**Hint 3:** The set $\mathcal{C}_n$ (resp. $\mathcal{C}_n/2$) is the set of all real numbers in $[0,1]$ that can be expressed using $0$ and $2$ (resp. $0$ and $1$) in base $3$ in the first $n$ decimal places (and any number from the $(n+1)$-th decimal place onwards).

Comment: Nice hints! So, in the third hint, $\mathcal{C} + \mathcal{C}/2$ is $x + y$ where $x$ can be expressing with $0$ and $2$ and $y$ with $0$ and $1$. Thus, Any $t \in [0,1]$ can be write as $x + y$ where $x \in \mathcal{C}$ and $y \in \mathcal{C}/2$, right?

Comment: @LucasCorrêa exactly. Moreover, in the case of the Cantor set, for most numbers $z\in [0,1]$, those $x\in\mathcal{C}$ and $y\in \mathcal{C}/2$ such that $x + y = z$ are unique. The exception being numbers like $0.1 = 0.022222222\ldots$.